# How does Django media works behind the scene?

Tags: python, django

I'm a bit curious about Django media. This question isn't about the usage itself, but about what happens behind the scene.

I have a production server with a `media` folder containing my media (obvious), this folder weights about 40Mo. When I run `./manage.py mediabackup` it generates a `tar` file of almost 900Mo.

I wonder how Django stores 900Mo (tar, compressed?) into a 40Mo folder. I guess it actually does some magic behind the scene, but what?

---

Edit: I displayed the size differently using `du`:

```
$ du -sh media
838M    media
```

When I do a simple `ls -l` I get something different:

```
drwxrwxr-x 469 root root   36864 Jan 30 10:14 media
```

But maybe my issue is a misunderstanding of linux `ls` command. I assumed `36864` would be the folder total size, but it doesn't seem like it.

Comment: I understand you use https://github.com/django-dbbackup/django-dbbackup#mediabackup to generate the backup. Can you check the contents of the generated `tar` file and compare them against the contents of the `media` folder?

Comment: @dukebody Just updated the main post. The content is exactly the same between the tar file and the media folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspect, `ls -l` won't give you the size of the *contents* of the `media` folder. Use `du -hs media` instead and you will see it's much bigger than 40 kb. :)

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/185764/how-do-i-get-the-size-of-a-directory-on-the-command-line.